# Indentation in question in examclass

Tags: indentation, exam, examdesign

How can I remove the indentation in question' text?[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}
%Set the font (output) encoding
%--------------------------------------
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
%Format the name of each exercise
\qformat{\textbf{\large Esercizio \thequestion}\hfill}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

 \question I would like to have no indentation here.
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the documentation p.33 with `\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
\setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%`